# Iterate and update json values with python

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I have the following json:

```
{
  "taskDefinition": {
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "memoryReservation": 1040,
        "mountPoints": [

        ],
        "name": "staging-web1",
        "image": "1234567.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/staging:staging-web",
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "REVISION",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "RELEASE_VERSION",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
            "value": ""
          }
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
            "awslogs-group": "\/ecs\/staging",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        },
        "portMappings": [

        ],
        "cpu": 0,
        "volumesFrom": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "memoryReservation": 1040,
        "mountPoints": [

        ],
        "name": "s-staging-nosql1",
        "image": "1234567.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/staging:staging-nosql",
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "REVISION",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "RELEASE_VERSION",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
            "value": ""
          }  
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
            "awslogs-group": "\/ecs\/staging",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        },
        "portMappings": [

        ],
        "cpu": 0,
        "volumesFrom": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "memoryReservation": 1040,
        "mountPoints": [

        ],
        "name": "s-staging-db1",
        "image": "1234567.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/staging:staging-db",
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "REVISION",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "RELEASE_VERSION",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
            "value": ""
          }  
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
            "awslogs-group": "\/ecs\/staging",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        },
        "portMappings": [

        ],
        "cpu": 0,
        "volumesFrom": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do with python is to adjust the REVISION, RELEASE_VERSION, and ENVIRONMENT under each environment in containerDefinitions.

I'm a total novice when it comes to python but what I am trying is as follows:

```
NEW_CONTAINER_DEF=$(echo "${PREVIOUS_TASK_DEF}" | python <(cat <<-EOF
import sys, json
json_data = json.load(sys.stdin)
for item in json_data['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions']:
    if json_data.get(['environment']['name'])  == "REVISION":
         item['environment']['value']  = "myrevision"
print json.dumps(json_data)
EOF
))
```

Needless to say the code above doesn't work. Can anyone with more python experience help me to understand how I can iterate and update the values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that calling `json.load` is simply serializing `the json` into a python [`dictionary`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). You can just modify that dictionary accordingly.

It appears that first you would like to iterate over all `taskDefinition.containerDefinitions`, then you would like to iterate over all the `environments` in those definitions and set the environment `value` if the environment `name` is `REVISION`. See this:

```
for item in json_data["taskDefinition"]["containerDefinitions"]:
    for env in item["environment"]:
         if env["name"] == "REVISION":
             env["value"] = "myrevision"
print json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)
```

Comment: Awesome. I've been banging my head off the wall trying all sorts of permutations trying to get this to work. I have experience programming in other languages but I'm a python newbie so I couldn't figure out where I was going wrong. Thank You!